# What's the best way to display currency format in VBA MsgBox?

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I have concatenated text and some basic calculations showing on my MsgBox. How can I get the number to display in currency format? I have placed a dollar sign before the calculations but it would be better if it had the proper currency format with 2 decimals. $1050.00

```
MsgBox "Total Cost is $" & (QuoteInput * 3 + QuoteInputTwo * 5 + 670), vbOKOnly, "White Glove Service"
```

Comment: Why not just use `Format$`? That's what it's for...

Comment: Try this way, please: `MsgBox "Total Cost is " & Format(QuoteInput * 3 + QuoteInputTwo * 5 + 670, "#####.00"), vbOKOnly, "White Glove Service"`

Comment: @FaneDuru It will not show any dollar sign.

Comment: @Harun24HR: Yes, I missed the '$' character in the format string. It should be `MsgBox "Total Cost is " & Format(QuoteInput * 3 + QuoteInputTwo * 5 + 670, "$#####.00"), vbOKOnly, "White Glove Service"`...

Answer (score 0):

May be you read all the comments to your question. I am just posting as answer same as comment. Try below and let us know your further feedback.

```
Sub FormatCurrency()
    MsgBox "Total Cost is " & Format$(QuoteInput * 3 + QuoteInputTwo * 5 + 670, "$#.00"), vbOKOnly, "White Glove Service"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *Format* and the magic format string "Currency" which is exactly for this:

```
MsgBox "Total Cost is " & Format(QuoteInput * 3 + QuoteInputTwo * 5 + 670, "Currency"), vbOKOnly, "White Glove Service"
```